# Using the Interactive QPython on Android, Can't Import from CWD

Tags: android, python, qpython

When using the interactive console in QPython on Android, chdir'ed to a directory containing .py files, attempts to import them result in 'module  not found'.  The problem is that sys.path has, as its first element, '', instead of '.'.  Setting sys.path[0] to '.', either before or after os.chdir(), fixes that.